# Intellij JPA Console with persistence.xml

Tags: spring, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm setting up a xml-free persistence JPA/Hibernate 4+/Spring 3+ using Intellij 13+. When I try to execute a query in the jpa console, I get the following error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialectt.PostgreSQL9Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
```

With the default postgres dialect, I get the same error. 
Any idea what's going on?

Configuration extract:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.wikiz.service.model.rep" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.pass}"/>
</bean>
```

And variables:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

Comment: Please add the `persistence.xml`.

Comment: OK. I think I got this but is going to be a bit long

Comment: @Deinum: The configuration is without persistence.xml file, and is instead configured with `packagesToScan` property

Comment: Did you try my answer? I am qurious to see if it worked

Comment: I am having the same issue with Intellij, looking for a solution as I want to test my JPQL

Answer (score 9):

Ok here it is.
I am not 100% sure if this helps your case but I think this is what you need to do:
Add a jdbc connection to your database from the database tab (usually to your right)
[image: Add a jdbc connection to your database]

Then add the hibernate facet to your module
Go to modules  (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) then add it:
[image]

Now you have enabled the persistance tab on your left (usually) and you can assign a datasource to your

Now add the hibernate configuration but you have to add the xml file of hibernate. I haven't tried it with just adding the spring application context instead of **hibernate.cfg.xml**. Maybe it will work...
[image]

Now you have enable the presistance configuration for intellij and you can assign a datasource to it.
[image]

Select that datasource that you want and you will be able to use the JPA console with your jpa POJOs and HSQLs 
[image]

Comment: You say: "I haven't tried it with just adding the spring application context instead of hibernate.cfg.xml. Maybe it will work..." --> 
That's exactly the point: it doesn't work on my machine. Is there a way to make it work??

Comment: This works...but I guess IntelliJ doesn't yet scan for entity manager data sources...if you add a session factory in one of your application context files, it does recognize the data source there...hopefully, folks at Jetbrains adds support for this in the future...

Comment: Does not work on mine too..Using spring boot with the configurations not in a xml file