# IntelliJ IDEA JPA console mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, console, mapping

I'm absolutely new to Hibernate framework and I can't handle one issue by myself)

I got some problems with using JPA console after building a JavaEE Persistence project in IntelliJ IDEA that similar to problems, described in these topics:

1. [JPA CONSOLE is not working intelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566331/jpa-console-is-not-working-intellij),
2. [Intellij JPA Console with persistence.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058936/intellij-jpa-console-with-persistence-xml).

So, I used next recommendations from topics to handle exceptions:

1) set user and password in *persistence.xml* file:

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
```

2) switch JPA version to 2.0 in *persistence.xml* file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
```

3) assign data sources to the persistence configuration.

BUT, I still can't use JPA console because of a mapping problems like these:

```
jpa-ql> select email from students
[2016-01-08 12:40:07] students is not mapped [select email from students]
jpa-ql> select * from students
[2016-01-08 12:40:10] unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [select * from students]
jpa-ql> select email from test.students
[2016-01-08 12:40:12] test.students is not mapped [select email from test.students]
```

Mapping itself:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students", schema = "test", catalog = "")
public class StudentsEntity {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String street;
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you added <mapping class = "your fully qualified class name" />  in config file?

Comment: "select * from blahblah" is obviously invalid JPQL, and no idea why you'd even try it. And the entry in persistence.xml is "<class>name</class>" not "<mapping class=...>"

Comment: I tried different queries) Yes, IDEA constructed mapping just fine, here: <class>TestSQL.StudentsEntity</class>, and... Oh, I get it... I should use modified classes names instead of table names... thanks for answers)

Answer (score 0):

This error occure when you add jpa to incorrect module. For example if you have multi modules and annotation based config, JPA should be applied as following image shown on module that consist main aplication runner and configureation.
After doing that, the is not mapped problem solved for me in jpa-ql console.

[image]